# Windows Forms Application that sorts a list of random number by using the Gnome Sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, gnome

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillArray();
        }
        private void FillArray() { Random rnd = new Random(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) { myArray[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100); } } 


        // Array of random integers
        static int max = 29;
        int[] myArray = new int[max];

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int outer = 0; outer < max; outer++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1])
                    {
                        // Swap routine
                        temp = myArray[i + 1];
                        myArray[i + 1] = myArray[i];
                        myArray[i] = temp;

                    }
                    ShowArray();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                }
            }
        }

                   private void ShowArray()
                   {
                   listBox1.Items.Clear();
                   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
 {
                   listBox1.Items.Add(myArray[i]);
 }
 }
    }
                }
```

// Hi, I'm trying to complete this but having trouble. Not sure if I am even going the right way about it. Any help would be appreciated. Here's the question:
 Create a Windows Forms Application that sorts a list of random number by using
the Gnome Sort algorithm. The program must use an Array of 29 integers. After
each iteration the program must display the Array.
Important: The swap routine must be in a separate method that uses arguments
to pass and return two Array elements.

Comment: Can't get FillArray to work either...

Comment: whats not working? where is FillArray?

Comment: The listBox is blank and I'm not sure how to FillArray at the start. Am I way off with the code or nearly there?

Comment: hi deise, you can fill in the constructor but i can see you commented out that code. if im not wrong u just want to show some random numbers in the combo box & on button click you want to sort them & every iterations u want to show them as well? can u show ur fillarray code?

Comment: I commented it out by mistake. I don't know how to write the code to for the fillarray,,,Yes your right that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: try this code... private void FillArray()
 {
  Random rnd = new Random();

  for(int i=0;i < 29; i++)
  {
   myArray[i] = rnd.Next(1,100);
  }
 }

Comment: Hi Sushil, I edited the code, have a look. Thank's for the fillarray code. What else do I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: happy to help. does that solve your problem? let me know if you face any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

This one is quick and dirty from your code. I start the gnome sort in a new task, so that the GUI not freezed during sorting. And ShowArray will be called using Invoke to avoid CrossThreadException. Take a look first:

```
// Array of random integers
private const int MAX = 29;
private readonly int[] myArray = new int[MAX];

private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FillArray();

  // Using Task to avoid GUI freeze
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    for (var outer = 0; outer < MAX; outer++)
    {
      for (var inner = 0; inner < MAX - 1; inner++)
      {
        if (myArray[inner] > myArray[inner + 1])
        {
          Swap(ref myArray[inner + 1], ref myArray[inner]);
        }
        ShowArray();
        Thread.Sleep(50);
      }
    }
  });
}

private void FillArray()
{
  var random = new Random();
  for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    myArray[i] = random.Next(1, 100);
  }
}

private void ShowArray()
{
  // Using Invoke to avoid CrossThreadException
  Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
  {
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
      listBox1.Items.Add(myArray[i]);
    }
  }));
}

private static void Swap(ref int var1, ref int var2)
{
  var temp_value = var1;
  var1 = var2;
  var2 = temp_value;
}
```

Comment: Everything looks ok except for the word "Task" has a red line under it    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>

Comment: Thank's a lot X.... Now I will have to understand how you did it and practice it. Very much appreciated. Spent most of the weekend on that lol. Now at least I will learn how its done.